# how can i match a string that follows few specific rules, like comes after some specific strings using spacy matcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, matcher

I have a pattern of strings that can determine the language word present in the string.

The sample pattern is as follows:

fluent in **language**

speak fluent **language**

fluently speak **language**

knows **language**

speak **language**

speaks **language**

knows fluent **language**

know fluent **language**

language: **language**

how can I find it using Spacy Matchers?

Example of sentences are

*looking for a female aged 20 who can speak fluent bengali and stays in mumbai*

Answer (score 0):

if your source language is English and close to what SpaCy was trained on, you could just use Named Entity Recognition to find the languages. If you do need to use patterns, there’s a good tool for exploring here: https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher